# "no child process" error when calling waitpid twice

Tags: linux, waitpid

For some reason, I have to call `waitpid` twice on the same child process:

Calling the `waitpid` the first time and there are no errors:

```
waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
```

The second time:

```
waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED);
```

An error occurred: "No child process". Is there anything wrong with my code?

Update:

If the child process have already exited after or before my first calling of `waitpid`, which means the parent process has reaped this child process, the second calling of `waitpid` then causes errors. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that the child terminated prior to the second `waitpid()` call? AFAIR, `waitpid()` waits for child process termination (or other change of state).

Comment: The parent process reaped child process by calling `waitpid`. If a child process has been reaped, it can't be `waitpid`. Is this correct?